# QML: Mouse wheel event propagation in ListView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

Have strange situation with `ListView` scrolling on mouse wheel. Have Items structure similar to this:

```
MainAppWindow {

    // Some  zoomable map item
    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    PopupMenu { // Simple Rectangle item
      anchors.top: parent.top
      width: 200
      height: parent.height / 2
      z: parent.z + 1

      ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        ...
        delegate: Item {
          ...
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClick: {
                    someHandler()
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

`ListView` with ***vertical*** scroll works and scrolls just fine until it stops at bounds (top or bottom - whatever) and after this mouse event starts to propagate to underlying layer and `ZoomableMap` starts to zoom which is not we want: should be propagated there only if `PopupMenu` is not visible. Adding

```
                onWheel: wheel.accepted = true
```

into `MouseArea` inside `ListView` delegate could partially solve the problem - it disables wheel and allows scrolling only by dragging the content. However better allow scrolling by the wheel as well. `MouseArea` in `PopupMenu` blocks wheel and dragging in the `ListView` completely as well - not helps also.

So what is problem here, how to fix? Or we doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you disable zooming/mouse interaction in `ZoomableMap` when `PopupMenu::visible == true`? (Need an `id` for the popup, of course.) Ideally `ZoomableMap` would have some property for that... in which case it's probably the simplest option.

Comment: @MaximPaperno Yes, that could be the solution. Thanks! Need to add another `MouseArea` into `ZoomableMap` which blocks all mouse events and is disabled by default and enable it only if popup is visible. Ids exist of course.

Comment: Cool, sure will be easier than following the [Flickable code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickflickable.cpp.html#_ZN15QQuickFlickable10wheelEventEP11QWheelEvent)...  :-)   Actually I don't see any API (or even hack) which would allow the flickable to keep "stealing" (grabbing) the mouse after it's done scrolling.

Comment: @MaximPaperno yeah, very strange behavior or even Qt bug.

Comment: @MaximPaperno however could be some bug in `ZoomableMap` as well.

Comment: What is `ZoomableMap` anyway? If it happens to be a QtLocation `Map` type then there's `Map::gesture::enabled` property (not that I've ever tried it). Yea with a wheel-type input I'd expect whatever was directly under the cursor to maintain focus/grab and prevent propagating. But admittedly this is "desktop" mentality and I guess wheel events can be synthesized from touch or trackpad where there's no cursor per sé... so it's a tough call to cover all situations. Seems like a Flickable property to control this could be useful.

Comment: @MaximPaperno if interesting - map: [FlightMap](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/blob/master/src/PlanView/PlanView.qml#L436) and [MouseArea](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/blob/master/src/PlanView/PlanView.qml#L758), which prevents mouse event propagation to the map - both based on `QtQuick.Controls 1`. Our `PopupMenu` uses recent `QtQuick.Controls 2.12` however [events leaks](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/pull/6154#issuecomment-557675414) are happen as well for some reason.

Comment: You're kidding, QGC? What a hilarious coincidence! I'm [very familiar](https://github.com/AutoQuad/qgroundcontrol_aq/graphs/contributors) with an old fork of it... :-)

Comment: @MaximPaperno - colleagues! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202925/discussion-between-aleksey-kontsevich-and-maxim-paperno).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add another `MouseArea` into `PopupMenu` which blocks all mouse events and is disabled by default and enable it only if popup is visible (optional):

> **enabled: popupMenu.visible**

```
MainAppWindow {

    // Some  zoomable map item
    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    PopupMenu { // Simple Rectangle item
        id: popupMenu
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: 200
        height: parent.height / 2
        z: parent.z + 1

        MouseArea {
            id: mapMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            enabled: popupMenu.visible
            preventStealing:true
            hoverEnabled:   true
            onWheel:        { wheel.accepted = true; }
            onPressed:      { mouse.accepted = true; }
            onReleased:     { mouse.accepted = true; }
        }

        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            clip: true
            ...
            delegate: Item {
                ...
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClick: {
                        someHandler()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note:** however this solution does not work if `ListView` (or any other control) is a `Map` descendant item: item dragging causes map panning. To make it work need to make it at least sibling.